# How Do I Obtain an Access Key (AK/SK)?

Tags: security, cloud, huawei-cloud

In Huawei Cloud, how do I obtain an Access Key (AK/SK) key pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An access key comprises an access key ID (AK) and secret access key (SK), and is used as a long-term identity credential to sign your requests for HUAWEI CLOUD APIs.

1. Log in to HUAWEI CLOUD and click Console in the upper right corner.

[image]

2. On the management console, hover over the username in the upper right corner and choose My Credentials from the drop-down list.

[image]

3. Choose Access Keys from the navigation pane.
4. Click Create Access Key, and enter the verification code or password.

[image]

```
NOTE:
• You can create a maximum of two access keys. The quota cannot be increased. If you already have two access keys, you can only delete an access key and create a new one.
• To change an access key, delete it and create a new one.
```

5. Click OK to generate an access key and download it.
   After the access key is created, view the AK in the access key list and view the SK in the downloaded CSV file.

```
NOTE:

• Download the access key file and keep it properly. If the download page is closed, you will not be able to download the access key. However, you can create a new one.
• Open the CSV file in the lower left corner, or choose Downloads in the upper right corner of the browser and open the CSV file.
• Keep your access keys secure and change them periodically for security purposes. To change an access key, delete it and create a new one.
```

**Source** - https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/usermanual-ca/ca_01_0003.html